# Где располагается файл деобфускации Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-studio, gradle

Написал проект. Залил в `Google Play`, поймал первую ANR, но без файла деобфускации не могу понять причину сбоя. Где его можно найти ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Самостоятельно нашел ответ на свой вопрос.

Файл деобфускации проекта Android Studio располагается здесь:

`<MyProjectName>\app\build\outputs\mapping\release\mapping.txt`